# find file newermt and grep file content not working

Tags: linux, grep, find

I am having trouble with the Linux find and grep commands. Basically I need to CD to a directory, recursive find all example.txt files modified after a particular date and then execute grep on those files. The command below is working (somewhat) but it gives multiple results of same file and I am not sure how stable it is.

```
find ./ -name "example.xml" -newermt "2018-01-01" -exec grep -r "videoplayer.1" /. \;
```

Comment: Your missing `{}` at the end of grep! Perhaps this would help: `find ./ -name "example.xml" -newermt "2018-01-01" -exec grep -r "videoplayer.1" {} \;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find ./ -name "example.xml" -newermt "2018-01-01" -exec grep -r "videoplayer.1" /. \;
```

This would `find`, starting at the current directory `./`, files with the -name `example.xml` that are newer (in modification time) than `2018-01-01` and for each of them, execute the command `grep -r "videoplayer.1" /.`.

But we see that the `grep` command does *not* take the file name found by `find` into account, but instead the command is always constant. Furthermore, it starts a recursive (`-r`) search from the *root of the filesystem* (`/.`). Now, that may be a typo (`./` vs. `/.`), but the meaning changes completely.

Even with `grep -r ... ./`, the search would be recursive starting from the current directory, and with `-exec`, that's the directory where `find` was started.

With `find -exec`, you need to use the `{}` placeholder to tell `find` where to insert the filename currently being processed. So

```
find ./ -name "example.xml" -newermt "2018-01-01" -exec grep  "videoplayer.1" {} \;
```

To run `grep videoplayer.1 filename` on all files named `example.xml` that are newer than January 1st 2018.

Actually, you could do replace the `\;` that terminates the `-exec` command with a `+` to have `find` pass multiple files to one invocation of `grep`. That would make the whole job faster, since less processes need to be started:

```
find ./ -name "example.xml" -newermt "2018-01-01" -exec grep  "videoplayer.1" {} \+
```

Also, if you want to make sure `grep` lists the name of the file it's processing, you can use the `-H` flag (in at least GNU and BSD `grep`):

> ```
>   -H, --with-filename
> ```
>
> Print the file name for each match.  This is the default when
>                 there is more than one file to search.

(An alternative to `-H` would be to add something like `/dev/null` to the list of files given to `grep`)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, this is the final version of the command which I am planning to use -  find ./ -name "example.xml" -newermt "2018-01-01" -exec grep "videoplayer.1" {} ./ \;

Basically the same as the suggested above but with extra "./" so I can see the path and file.

Comment: @VitaliyTerziev, yeah, GNU and BSD grep have the `-H` option, which tells it to print the file name in any case. It's what happens by default if multiple files are listed. Also, I forgot to mention `find -exec ... {} +`, which would be better. Edited notes on both.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the details and examples, I have final version of the command now. :)

find ./ -name "example.xml" -newermt "2018-01-01" -exec grep -H "videoplayer.1" {} \+

Answer (score 2):

I would think the correct form of that command is:

```
find ./ -name "example.xml" -newermt "2018-01-01" -exec grep -r "videoplayer.1" {} \;
```

Missing the `{}` part in the `find` command. Your find results aren't being passed to grep.

Comment: Thanks, George. I think your solution is working but id does not show the path of the file, I've modified it a bit - find ./ -name "example.xml" -newermt "2017-01-08" -exec grep "videoplayer.1" {} ./ \; Do you think that it is reliable?

Comment: Remove the `\;` and use `+` and see if it helps

Comment: With `\;` you are passing only a single file at a time to `grep`, so it won't print the filename by default - you will need to add the `-H` option if you want it to add the name. Or add a `-print` to the find command.

Comment: Would `+` not be ok too, and the `-print` prints all file names

Comment: Thanks guys, so @steeldriver / George, sorry for asking again same question but the command line, is it reliable for what I am looking for? I will try the -H flag as well for getting the file names/paths.

Comment: George, I've marked ilkkachu's reply as answer because of the structured and detailed explanation. However I've +1 yours yesterday since it is also correct to some extent.

Comment: @VitaliyTerziev as you wish my lord, :)!